# Creating new shapefile using pyshp

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I am trying to strip data out of an existing shapefile to create new shapefiles. I have made the loop work, and made the new file, but I cannot work out why I cannot add records to the new file I am writing:

```
import shapefile as shp


coord1 = (39.737094, -121.543857)
coord2 = (39.651237, -121.403610)

sfinput = shp.Reader(r'C:\...\fire_archive_M6_98806.shp')
w = shp.Writer(r'C:\...\Output')
w.fields = sfinput.fields


for i in range(len(sfinput.records())):
    #test if within latitude
    if sfinput.record(i)[0] >= coord2[0] and sfinput.record(i)[0] <= coord1[0]:
        #test if within longitude
        if sfinput.record(i)[1] <= coord2[1] and sfinput.record(i)[1] >= coord1[1]:
            w.record(sfinput.record(i))
```

The error I am recieving:

```
record = [recordList[i] for i in range(fieldCount)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `fieldCount` sounds like the number of *attributes*, while `recordList` sounds like the number of *records*.

Comment: I have worked out how to set one record to the shape file that I am writing: `w.record=sfinput.record(i)` This just seems to write over the record already assigned to `w` though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import shapefile as shp

sfinput = shp.Reader(r"C:\...\fire_archive_M6_98806.shp")

with shp.Writer(r"C:\...\Output") as w:
    w.fields = sfinput.fields[1:] # skip first deletion field
    for feature in sfinput.iterShapeRecords(): # iteration on both record and shape for a feature
            w.record(*feature.record) # * for unpacking tuple
            w.shape(feature.shape)
```

`shapefile` doesn't manage CRS, therefore don't forget to copy `.prj` file.

```
import os
import shutil
prj_file = r"C:\...\fire_archive_M6_98806.prj"
if os.path.exists(prj_file):
    shutil.copy(prj_file, r"C:\...\Output.prj")
```