# Clip shapefile by polygon

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I am trying to clip shapefile by polygon with following code but I had this error. How can I correct the error?

```
import shapefile
# Create a reader instance
r = shapefile.Reader(r"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\buffer\My_buffer.shp")
# Create a writer instance
w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)
# Copy the database fields to the writer
w.fields = list(r.fields)
xmin = 553324.702
xmax = 558332.073
ymin = 3597544.402
ymax = 3600507.908
for road in r.iterShapeRecords():
    # Shape geometry, Database Attributes
    geom = road.shape
    rec = road.record
    # Get the bounding box of the shape
    sxmin, symin, sxmax, symax = geom.bbox
    if sxmin <  xmin: continue
    elif sxmax > xmax: continue
    elif symin < ymin: continue
    elif symax > ymax: continue
    # Road is inside our selection box.
    # Add it to the new shapefile
    w._shapes.append(geom)
    w.records.append(rec)
w.save(r"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\buffer\cliped_file.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: What error did you get when you ran the code that you have presented?

Comment: It looks like you have copied the non-working code from the question above. The error you are getting now is because you need to pass a save path argument as `string` type to the `shapefile.Writer` class constructor instead of the `integer` value returned by `r.shapeType`. It is likely you will get additional errors though, even once that's corrected. Look at the answers to that question for possible working solutions.

Comment: You can also check the PyShp docs here: https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/clipping-shapefile-in-pure-python

Comment: i got a good result when i execute this code when clip a shape LINE by box (xmin,ymin,  xmax, ymax) but i did not find any results in the when i tested with shape POLYGONE (area)